# Which is the latest DirectX version for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, directx

Which is latest DirectX latest version for Windows 7? 9, 10 or 11? And from where can I download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It came with DirectX 11, and that's the latest available.

See [DirectX Releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX#Releases) @ Wikipedia.

Comment: Just to note few games/programs will require newer editions of DirectX 9, which are not available with Win 7 - as of now Feb 2010 is the latest edition http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0CEF8180-E94A-4F56-B157-5AB8109CB4F5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Here is official site: **[DirectX download and security updates](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=directx)**.  It's the best place to look.